# Making Python3 default on command line

Tags: python-3

I have been trying to run the Jupyter notebook on my Pi but the Kernels will not install into Jupiter even though I downloaded them through the Pi's Software download window. A little bit stumped and the only thing I feel it could be is that its not the default version on the command line. Any advice would be a huge help

Comment: What is our question, and how is it related to the title?

Comment: As far as I see the question does not belong to Raspberry Pi. What do you mean by running python3 as default on the command line? You can run **python**, that will execute python 2.7 on Raspbian and you can run **python3**, that will execute python 3.5. Executing python 3.5 when calling **python** is strongly discouraged because it may confuse the operating system that calls **python** but needs python 2.7 for its system tasks.

Comment: Do you mean making python the default from terminal in Raspbian?

Comment: I think this speaks to the question you are asking. https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3#